# PHP ORM Mysql ordering using REGEX

Tags: php, mysql, regex

You see I have a set of entries to be ordered alphabetically. Though some of the entries starts with "The". What I want is to ignore "The" and start sorting from the next word. For example:

```
$titles->order_by("name", "ASC")->find_all() // Sample query
```

- Abraham
- Panorama
- The Malevolent

What I want:

- Abraham
- **The Malevolent** // Ignore "the" in the sorting
- Panorama

What I really really want"

- Abraham
- **Malevolent, The** // Kinda rearranged
- Panorama

How can I do that here?:

```
$titles->order_by("name", "ASC")->find_all();
```

If not then what may you suggest?

I have a strong hunch that using REGEX would seal the deal. Though I don't know how without going into the software level.

Im using Kohana 3 ORM and only started last month. Please go easy on me.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a conditional `select` and a `substring` function; the exact name of these functions may vary depending on the dialect you use. In Transact-SQL:

```
select if( left(name,3)='The', SUBSTRING(name,5), name) as name 
from table 
order by name
```

And another way: use a conditional to find the 'The ' part, and replace it with an empty string:

```
select TRIM(
  if(INSTR(shipnam,'The ') > 0, INSERT(shipnam,INSTR(shipnam,'Hyundai'),4,''),
  if(INSTR(shipnam,' The ') > 0, INSERT(shipnam,INSTR(shipnam,'Hyundai'),5,''),shipnam))
) 
as shipname from tablename order by shipname
```

Change according to your column and table name.